# Including files causes multiple definition errors for globals

Tags: c++, include, global-variables, multiple-definition-error

I am getting a funky multiple definition error. The include structure is as follows:

```
MAIN -> VM -> BACKEND
```

Main includes vm which includes backend.

I have three global `char *` pointers in backend, and it is the members that I get the multiple definition errors.

I get multiple definitions in `vm.cpp`, `main.cpp` and `moc_vm.cpp` (I use Qt).

I tried declaring the pointers as external in the rest of the sources, but it didn't help. All preprocessor guards are in place, and I don't know why I am getting the error, since they are obviously defined in only one place...

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is strange, I can include BACKEND into MAIN and there are no problems, only when the chain is MAIN>VM>BACKEND I get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Define them as external in the header file. 
Define them (not as external) once in a single cpp file.

You should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extern char *name;` and then in ONE of your .cpp files have `char *name = "Something";`.

Comment: Well, either way, you have it in a single .cpp file, and define and assign it there, declare it `extern` in a header file that gets included to all places where it is used. What you assign it with is up to you...

Comment: It is declared in a header only file (no cpp compliment). Also, see the edit I made to the question.

Comment: Without seeing source code it's not easy to say, but it doesn't matter which .cpp file you use - as long as it includes the .h file that declares the variable. If you include the header in more than one .cpp file [directly or indirectly] then it will be a multiple definition problem, because the linker finds multiple variables defined with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the pointers to static so they are not linked externally. They are not accessed in any other source anyway. So it was a linkage issue after all...

Comment: You should learn about unnamed namespaces. They are preferred over static globals in C++.

Comment: Are you SURE that you want more than one copy of the pointers? They are not pointing to some data that is changing then?

Comment: I am sure I don't need to access those pointers from any other source file. What do copies have to do with that?

Comment: @JesseGood - I think C++ should have public and private for free functions and objects too, and use that to define if they are to be accessible and linked or not. Static has too many meanings in different contexts...